# Possible to make a Google sheet macro available to all sheets I access?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macro

I have created a very basic google sheet macro that reformats columns by automatically adjusting their widths, and then widening the column(s) by a certain amount, to avoid crowding columns next to each other.

I tend to attach this macro to a lot of sheets regularly, is there a way for me to add it to my account in such a way that if I just click "new sheet" in google sheet, that macro is available to use in there, without me having to manually add it as a new macro to that file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking it's not easy to make a macro available to all the spreadsheets.

It's possible to create an add-on to make available a Google Apps Script project to all the spreadsheet but at this time they don't support macros.

In order to make a bit easier to distribute the last version of your macros, it's possible to create a Google Apps Script library, but it will still necessary to have a bounded Google Apps Script project to make the macros feature access the library.

I'm wondering if the Google Apps Script API might be used to automate the process (create a new spreadsheet and add to it macros). Anyway,  for most macro users this will be overkilling.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts